# VS Code needs a Python Interpreter. Why is this necessary?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, interpreter

I'm new to visual studio code and running a simple html application.  When running (F5), VS Code complains about "select a python Interpreter". It's also in the blue bar at the bottom. Why does it need this since I'm not doing Python?

Comment: what do you expect to happen when pressing F5 for a workspace with HTML files

Comment: Read this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) before you start python coding.

Comment: The point is I'm not doing anything related to Python.  I have just a simple html and css webpage.  I expect the webpage to launch in Google Chrome showing just an <h1> and a <p> tag.

Comment: Uninstall Python extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you have Python selected as your language.. VSCode will help with syntax if the correct language is selected.. bottom right of the windown (in the blue bar) look for "Python" Click it, it'll take you to the search bar, look for HTML and select it as your language.